# Oauth2 using Python 3.4 and Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-oauth

I'm trying to authorize my django application using oauth2 in order to  interact with the google content for shopping API. However, I'm experiencing issues with oauth2 along the way.

I have oauth2client and google-api-python-client installed. My view is as follows:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secret.json')

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content',
    redirect_uri='https://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/oauth2callback')


def get_account_ids(service):
    accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()
    ids = []
    if accounts.get('items'):
        for account in accounts['items']:
            ids.append(account['id'])
    return ids


@login_required
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()    
    if credential is None:
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(
            settings.SECRET_KEY, user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        f = FlowModel(id=user, flow=FLOW)
        f.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build('content', 'v2', http=http)
        ids = get_account_ids(service)
        return render(
            request, 'index.html', {'ids':ids})


@login_required
def auth_return(request):
    user = request.user
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, bytes(request.GET['state'], 'utf-8'), user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.GET, http=None)
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/oauth2/")
```

At first, I was getting an error from the auth_return view that the string retuned by *request.GET['state']* had no encoding, so I changed this:

```
if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, request.GET['state'], user):
```

to this:

```
if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, bytes(request.GET['state'], 'utf-8'), user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

and the error was gone. However, I'm now getting the error:

```
'bytes' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

from the index view. The exact line causing the exception is:

```
http = credential.authorize(http)
```

It seems like this is being caused by the earlier change I made. I'm new to using oauth2 and I have spent a lot of hours already trying to debug. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer.

It seems the django_orm module in oauth2client uses the 'to_python' function in the CredentialsField definition, which doesn't work and thus returns the Base64 data back.

TO solve this, you have to edit the oauth2client/django_orm source definition from:

```
class CredentialsField(models.Field):
```

to:

```
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
class CredentialsField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.Field)):
```

This will allow it to return the Credentials object for both Python2 and Python3.

Make sure you delete the currently stored credentials object first since it is a string object and not a Credentials object.